# Receive SEND_ACTION including images from browser in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Android application that accepts the selected text from the browser. I can do this either with process_text or with send:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

First one registers on the text selector and second one registers on the share button. Once my activity is triggered I can access the text as expected. However, I would like to access the images as well as the text.

In the following image, one can see that the small picture is blue because it has been selected. But that picture is not sent over with any of the actions defined.

[image]

What's the way to access that content? I've tried to set "text/html" but then it does not trigger it.

Comment: You could see if you are being given a `CharSequence` rather than a `String`, where there is an `ImageSpan` representing the image.

Comment: @CommonsWare you mean `this.getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT)` ? It doesn't include information about the image, only the text. BTW `this.getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT)` is null

Comment: "It doesn't include information about the image, only the text" -- OK, if there is no `ImageSpan`, then I suspect that you are out of luck.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there a way to access this info? If I copy the selection and paste it in gmail the image appears (although not through sharing)

Comment: If you can work with copy/paste, `ClipboardManager` may have a few MIME types of content for you, and obviously one has image data. `ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT` probably focuses purely on the text, and `ACTION_SEND` will depend on who is doing the sending.